# http delete in Ionic 2

Tags: json, angular, ionic2, angular-http

I just wonder how to implement http delete in Ionic2(Angular2). I do have an JSON API and I simply wanted to delete a specific data in it.

I wanted to delte this data:

`this.http.delete('http://sample.com/XXX/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1`

I know that it is just a basic question but I have no idea how to implement. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the code on your api look like?

Comment: I still dont have a code sir to delete. Im sorry but Im a newbie.

Comment: I want to delete the all the data with that API url.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to make sure you have the permission to execute DELETE on the URL.

Secondly, make sure your url is correct:
`http://sample.com/XXX/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1`

Finally, the delete command for `Http` is

```
delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
```

it returns `Observable` which means it wouldn't be execute until you invoke `subscribe()` on it:

```
this.http.delete(YOUR_URL).subscribe(
    resp => console.log('deleted'),
    error => console.log('error occur, delete fail')
);
```

Comment: "until you invoke subscribe() on it:" very easy step to be forgotten by beginners

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to angular 2 http [here](https://angular.io/guide/http) (which is what Ionic 2 uses)

It will look something like this:

```
     delete() : Observable<any> {

         return this.http.delete(http://sample.com/XXX/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1)

     }
```

then you can use it else where like so:

```
this.service.delete().subscribe(()=>{
    //do something after deleted
})
```

On the PHP side you will need to grab the variables:

```
$req = $_GET['filter']
```